# Trouble creating a link to delete a query in Django

Tags: django

I have a table of items that print from what currently resides within the users database. My intentions are that, for when I loop through the queries, and print them onto the page that there is a delete button. Keep in mind, the user is logged in to view these.
I just have code in here that I tested, but get a pile of errors.  I want the link to pass in the parameter of the primary key so it can be deleted.

## Views

```
def deleter(request, id, username):

    if username == request.user.username:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        ti = TaskItem.objects.get(pk = id)
        ti.delete()
        return HttpResponse('deleted')
    return HttpResponse('not deleted')
```

## Models

```
class TaskItem(models.Model):
    taskn = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
    usern = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #Created field will add a time-stamp to sort the tasks from recently added to oldest
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', default=timezone.now, editable = False)
    created_time = models.TimeField('time created', auto_now_add = True, editable = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.taskn + " at " + str(self.created_time)
```

## URLs

```
url(r'^user/(\w+)/delete/(\d+)/$', deleter),
url(r'^user/(\w+)/submitted/$', task_submission, name='submitted')
```

Comment: where is the url function for that particular view? How is the url call made from the template? What are the pile or errors you get?

Comment: Added my new changes, should make more sense. Throwing in http://localhost:8000/user/admin/delete/24/ and it says not deleted. Meaning the request is equalling the current logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

```
def deleter(request, id, username)
```

The order of the parameters made the difference for me.

Link creation in template was:

```
<td><a href="/user/{{ user.username }}/delete/{{ task.pk }}">Remove</a></td>
```

Comment: You should update your `urls.py` and give your route a name: `url(r'^user/(\w+)/delete/(\d+)/$', deleter, name='deleter')` so you can reference the route in your template without hard coding paths: `<a href="{% url "deleter" user.username task.pk %}">Remove</a>`. You won't have to touch your template code in the future if you ever decide to change the path in `urls.py`.